# Add to a variable inside an each method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function that iterate through a collection and add some value to a variable `$totalSaleValue` that is outside of each function :

```
public function totalSaleValue()
{
     $totalSaleValue = 0;

    $this->products->each(function ($item, $key) use ($totalSaleValue){

        if (!empty($item->sale_price)) {
            $totalSaleValue += $item->sale_price * $item->pivot->stock;
        }

    });

    return $totalSaleValue;
}
```

But always `$totalSaleValue` return `0`.

What is problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the variable by reference:

```
$this->products->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$totalSaleValue) {
```